# Can get value of JSON in Go

Tags: json, parsing, go

I'm new in Go. I'm trying to read a JSON file and get a part of it for then operate with the values obtained. 
My JSON is in the file example.json:

```
{"results":[{"statement_id":0,"series":[{"name":"cpu/node_utilization","columns":["time","distinct"],"values":[[10,1],[11,3],[13,5]]}]}]}
```

So what I would like to get is the "values" for get the sum of all the elements. In this case: 1+3+5

Here is the code that I have. I'm available to get the results, but then I don't manage to get series.

Here is the code that I have:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // Open our jsonFile
    jsonFile, err := os.Open("example.json")
    // if we os.Open returns an error then handle it
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Successfully Opened example.json")
    // defer the closing of our jsonFile so that we can parse it later on
    defer jsonFile.Close()

    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)
    var all_data map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(byteValue), &all_data)
    fmt.Println(all_data["results"])
}
```

I've tried diferent solutions like 
    `all_data["results"].(map[string]interface{})["series"])`
But the problem is that the map is in an array, and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Use `[]` for slice types. E.g. `all_data["results"].([]map[string]interface{})`.

Comment: So how it should be in this case? I'm trying `data_results := all_data["results"].([]map[string]interface{})` but I get the error when I try to do a Println: `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []interface {}, not []map[string]interface {}`

Comment: I have found a solution with Struct, but I would like to see how how it could be solved with interfaces.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have solved defining an Struct.

```
package main

import (
"encoding/json"
"fmt"
"io/ioutil"
"os"
)


type AutoGenerated struct {
    Results []struct {
        StatementID int `json:"statement_id"`
        Series      []struct {
            Name    string   `json:"name"`
            Columns []string `json:"columns"`
            Values  [][]int  `json:"values"`
        } `json:"series"`
    } `json:"results"`
}

func main() {
    // Open our jsonFile
jsonFile, err := os.Open("example.json")
// if we os.Open returns an error then handle it
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println("Successfully Opened example.json")
// defer the closing of our jsonFile so that we can parse it later on
defer jsonFile.Close()


byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)
all_data := AutoGenerated{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(byteValue), &all_data)
fmt.Println(all_data.Results[0].Series[0].Values)
}
```

I have used this [web](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to generate automatically the Struct providing the JSON structure

Answer (score 0):

Using interfaces and map

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    byteValue := []byte(`{"results":[{"statement_id":0,"series":[{"name":"cpu/node_utilization","columns":["time","distinct"],"values":[[10,1],[11,3],[13,5]]}]}]}`)

    var all_data map[string][]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(byteValue), &all_data)
    fmt.Println("result:", all_data["results"])

    for _, r := range all_data["results"] {
        s := r.(map[string]interface{})
        fmt.Println("series:", s["series"])

        w := s["series"].([]interface{})
        for _, x := range w {
            y := x.(map[string]interface{})
            fmt.Println(y)

            z := y["values"].([]interface{})
            fmt.Println("values:", z)
            for _, v := range z {
                u := v.([]interface{})
                fmt.Println(u)
                for _, i := range u {
                    val := i.(float64)
                    fmt.Println(val)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```